# Why android app still can receive firebase notification even though the messaging service process not exists?

Tags: android

I wrote an app which implemented the FirebaseMessagingService; I killed the process which the service belongs to, but the app can still receive the notification from firebase console, except that I forced to stop the app.

So, I just want to know why the app can still receive the notification event though the service not alive? What's the mechanism of android?

Comment: I would guess that a FCM message is sent to your device, not the app, and the system starts the appropriate process to process the message

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience in Firebase, but in previous Google Cloud Messaging it was working this way: at first notifications (pushes) are received by Google Play Services and then redirected to your app starting proper broadcast receiver or service. probalby Firebase is working same way - it's starting new service when it is not running currently